# Where to put HTML Code and CSS Code for socialengine widget

Tags: widget, socialengine

I have purchased a social engine php licence and I am trying to create a widget for a site-wide search bar via the "Developer SDK." Where do i put html and css code please? Would it be in the themes and constants css or within the Controller php, Index tpl, or manifest php files.

If anyone can help it would be so appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Amanda.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code will be index.tpl and CSS file will in admin->apperance->theme editior

choose theme.css and add your CSS over there.

Note:css will not work if you choose the different theme in future.